# how to get multiple values by using ajax in handsontable

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, handsontable

I'm using the handsontable jquery in JSP Spring + Angular JS
I success already put data of first row by using ajax. 
But, my program is ignoring Second, third....... rows

```js
var
    objectData = [{
       pno_stock: "3200105009",
    pname_stock: "VALVE",
    capital_stock: "a",
    tracking_no_stock: "SE17",
    standard_stock: "SRT",
    unit_stock: "SET",  
    storage_code_stock: "C03",
    storage_name_stock: "",
    stock_amount_stock: "6",
    price_indicator_stock: "M",
    client_code_stock: "1244156104",
    client_name_stock: "A company"},
    {
        pno_stock: "3243334802",
     pname_stock: "COVER",
     capital_stock: "a",
     tracking_no_stock: "SE17",
     standard_stock: "",
     unit_stock: "EA",  
     storage_code_stock: "C03",
     storage_name_stock: "",
     stock_amount_stock: "3",
     price_indicator_stock: "M",
     client_code_stock: "1228182903",
     client_name_stock: "B company"}
    ],
    container3 = document.getElementById('example'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container3, {
    data: objectData,
    contextMenu: true,
    rowHeaders: true,        
    minSpareRows: 1,
    columns: [{
          data: 'pno_stock'         
      }, {
          data: 'pname_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'capital_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'tracking_no_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'standard_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'unit_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'storage_code_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'storage_name_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'stock_amount_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'price_indicator_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'client_code_stock'        
      }, {
          data: 'client_name_stock'        
      }],
  });
  
  
  var sourceRow = hot.getSourceDataAtRow(0), 

console.log('* the getSourceDataAtRow:');
console.log(sourceRow);
 

            
             $(document).ready(function () { // DOM hierarchy constructed. Ready to attach event handlers and run jQuery code etc.
                 $("#Submit").click(function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     //var tableData = $("#example").handsontable('sourceRow');             
                     var formDataJson = JSON.stringify(sourceRow);
                     alert("before jQuery : " + formDataJson);
                     jQuery.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         headers: {
                             'Accept': 'application/json',
                             'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'                              
                         },
                         'url': "/yboard/insert1",
                         'data':  formDataJson,
                         'dataType': 'json',
                         'success': function (e) {
                          console.log(formDataJson);                               
                         },
                         'error': function() {
                    alert("Loading failed!" +"\n" );
                    console.log(formDataJson); 
                    
                   },
                     });
                 });
             });

function showBootstrapModal() {
  $('.modal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: true,
  });

  $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("hidden");
  });

  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("shown");
    hot.render();
  });
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btn').click(showBootstrapModal);
});
    
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="handsontableForm"> 
          <div id="example"></div>
          <INPUT id="Submit" TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit" style="margin-top: 50px;">
       </form>
<div style="text-align:left">
    <label id="serverResults"></label>
```

I tried to change variable sourceRow 
from 'var sourceRow = hot.getSourceDataAtRow(0)'
to 'var sourceRow = hot.getSourceData()'

and I checked all normal datas in console screen
But, also I got 'Loading failed!',
What's problem in this code?

---

Oh... I realized my java code also have problems...

my xml code is ...

```
<insert id="insertYboardStock" parameterType="YboardStock">
    INSERT INTO supply_stock(capital_stock, pno_stock, pname_stock, storage_code_stock, storage_name_stock, price_indicator_stock, unit_stock,
    stock_amount_stock, tracking_no_stock, standard_stock, client_code_stock, client_name_stock)        
    VALUES(#{capital_stock}, #{pno_stock}, #{pname_stock}, #{storage_code_stock}, #{storage_name_stock}, #{price_indicator_stock}, #{unit_stock},
    #{stock_amount_stock}, #{tracking_no_stock}, #{standard_stock}, #{client_code_stock}, #{client_name_stock})
</insert>
```

my controller code is..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert1", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
@ResponseBody
public ResultJSON insertYboardStock(@RequestBody YboardStock yboardstock) {
    ResultJSON resultJSON = new ResultJSON();
    yboardService.insertYboardStock(yboardstock);
    resultJSON.setSuccess(true);
    return resultJSON;
}
```

I don't know this is enough code to ask about it.
I guess single value inserting program can't put multiple values.
I will try to fix XML code by put 'foreach' function.

Answer (score 0):

First, I touched this javascript problem.
but it was the service problem.

I fixed java code like bellow

```
public int insertYboardStock(List<YboardStock> list);
```

and also XML

```
<insert id="insertYboardStock" parameterType="YboardStock">
    INSERT INTO supply_stock(capital_stock, pno_stock, pname_stock, storage_code_stock, storage_name_stock, price_indicator_stock, unit_stock,
    stock_amount_stock, tracking_no_stock, standard_stock, client_code_stock, client_name_stock)        
    VALUES
     <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=" , ">
    (#{item.capital_stock}, #{item.pno_stock}, #{item.pname_stock}, #{item.storage_code_stock}, #{item.storage_name_stock}, #{item.price_indicator_stock}, 
     #{item.unit_stock},    #{item.stock_amount_stock}, #{item.tracking_no_stock}, #{item.standard_stock}, #{item.client_code_stock}, #{item.client_name_stock})
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Finally, I succeed putting all datas in the Mysql Database  :)